# Discrete Wavelet Transform and Gaussian decay

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-analysis, wavelets, hermite-polynomials

I have a question regarding the possibility of constructing a Discrete Wavelet Transform based on a scaling function having Gaussian decay (and no more decay than that). More specifically, I am thinking in using a scaling function which might be a **finite** linear combination of Hermite functions.

I recall that the Hermite functions $\left\lbrace h_n\right\rbrace_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ defined by 
$$h_n(x)=(-1)^n (2^n n! \sqrt{n})^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \tfrac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$$
form an orthonormal basis in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

According to the book *Ten lectures on Wavelets* by I. Daubechies (see p. 145), a strategy to build examples of new orthonormal wavelet bases may have as a starting point a choice of a suitable scaling function $\phi$ which satisfies the following properties:

- $\phi$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{\phi}$ have a reasonable decay,
- there exists a sequence $c\in l^2(\mathbb{Z})$  such that
  $$\phi(x)= \sum_n c_n \phi(2x-n), $$
- there are numbers $0<\alpha$, $\beta<+\infty$ such that 
  $$\alpha \leq \sum_{l\in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\phi}(\xi+2\pi l)|^2\leq \beta,$$
- $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\,dx \neq 0$.

My question is: **is it known if a scaling function satisfying these properties and such that it is a finite linear combination of Hermite functions exist?**

The fourth condition imply that we could only take even Hermite functions $h_{2n}$ since $h_{2n+1}$ are odd functions; but it is not clear to me whether
we can find finite linear combinations of even Hermite functions such that the second and third conditions hold.

I find that this is a rather natural question since Hermite functions have gaussian decay and are eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform, thus, they have good space-frequency localization properties. However, I was not able to find an answer to my question in the literature.

I am aware about the Mexican Hat Wavelet (MHW), which is nothing else than the second derivative of the Gaussian function, but everything I found in the literature regarding the MHW in an Euclidean setting is related to Continuous Wavelet Transforms, not DWT.

Comment: I am not aware of such a construction. I think the second condition really is the crux (the third condition seems to be easier to fulfill…).

Comment: I do agree with you.